# Create iteration for all projects in the organisation

Tags: azure, post, azure-devops, iteration, postman

We have our projects at a product level in Azure DevOps, and at last count we had 94 products.  What I need to find a way of doing is creating the same iterations for all projects (dedicated for R&D time)

Using Postman I tried this:

```
 POST https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/Project1/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?api-version=5.0
```

and this as the body:

```
{"name": "Research and Development 2020-11-02", "attributes": {"startDate": "2020-11-02T00:00:00Z","finishDate": "2020-11-06T00:00:00Z"}}
```

It worked to an extent because it created an iteration for me for one project, but it ended up lost in the project (it wasn't appearing as a listed sprint on the backlogs page until I went looking for it in Project Settings).

Is there a way I can loop through all of my DevOps projects using Postman, and also how do I drop the iteration/sprint in so it's visible without needing to track it down on project settings?

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT - I tried it today and it worked perfectly, thank you.  I'm interested to learn a bit more though and hoping you could help?  If I wanted to exclude some projects how would I go about that?  Of what I created today, I was asked to remove a couple (which was fine) but if it gets too big a number I wouldn't want to do this manually. Would the best approach be to specify ones to include or ones to exclude (I'm assuming exclude since that's a smaller number??)

Comment: Hi @MattR. I could understand your requirement. For the new requirement, we cannot achieve it directly through rest api. So I have found a workaround to achieve it. Based on my test, it could work. Please check the Update. If it could meet your requirements, you could consider accepting it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can loop through all of my DevOps projects using Postman, and also how do I drop the iteration/sprint in so it's visible without needing to track it down on project settings?

Here is a powershell sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

ForEach( $project in $response.value.name ) 
{

   
  
    $url1="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/$($project)/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?api-version=5.0"
   

    $JSON = @'
    {
      "name": "Research9", "attributes": {"startDate": "2020-11-02T00:00:00Z","finishDate": "2020-11-06T00:00:00Z"}
    }
'@

    $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

    ForEach($id in $response1.identifier)
    {
     echo $id
     echo $project
  
    $url2="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/$($project)/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0"
   
         $body = "{
            `"id`": `"$id`"
          }"

    $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json
       
        
    }
}
```

**Explanation：**

This sample can traverse all projects, create iterations at the same time, and finally add Iteration to the team

The [first Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is used to list the project name.

The Second Rest API is used to create a Iteration.

The [Third Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/post%20team%20iteration?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is used to add the Iteration to the default team. Then you could see the Iteration in the Backlogs.

In this case, it's visible without needing to track it down on project settings.

**Update:**

Please try the following script:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$ExcludeList =  "Docker", "Azure","ProjectNAME"


ForEach( $project in $response.value.name ) 
{


   if ($ExcludeList | Where-Object {$project -like $_}) {
     
     echo $project
     echo "No Add"
   
   }

   else{
  
    $url1="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/$($project)/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?api-version=5.0"
   

    $JSON = @'
    {
      "name": "Research10", "attributes": {"startDate": "2020-11-02T00:00:00Z","finishDate": "2020-11-06T00:00:00Z"}
    }
'@

    $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

    ForEach($id in $response1.identifier)
    {
     echo $id
     echo $project
  
    $url2="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/$($project)/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0"
   
         $body = "{
            `"id`": `"$id`"
          }"

    $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json
       
        
    }
    }
}
```

The Rest API doesn't support excluding the projects(Based On name). But in Powershell,you can exclude these projects by judging the project name.

```
$ExcludeList =  "Docker", "Azure"


   if ($ExcludeList | Where-Object {$project -like $_}) {
     
     echo $project
     echo "No Add"
   
   }
```

If the Project name is in the list, the project will not create a Iteration.

Comment: I've had a more thorough look through today (a consequence of creating an unwanted sprint on a few projects) and although it seems to create iterations for the majority, there's a few that haven't created  (either with the original run or the second which had the exclude list populated).  I've had a look at permissions but I'm the organisation admin and a project collection admin so I don't think it's that. Have you come across that before?

Comment: The first Rest API displays 100 results - is that the limit on results it can bring back??  Does that likely mean I'd need to list the projects in a different way?

Comment: Hi @MattR. Could you please try to add the parameter `$top={$top}` to the First URL. For example: `https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/projects?$top=300&api-version=6.0`

Comment: @MattR. Here is a ticket about this  issue, you could refer to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344163/azure-devops-rest-api-returns-only-100-projects

Comment: Hi @MattR. Feel free to let me know if it could work. I will still be here to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Many thanks again. That makes sense.  I had to add a ` as well (I saw that on the link you shared) but that parameter was just what I needed.